# Is this a misquotation?

Tags: quoting

When using quotes in academic articles there is often a need to simplify things, without being accused of manipulating the original meaning. Consider the paragraph below in Adam Smith's Wealth of Nations:

> The natural effort of every individual to better his own condition, when suffered to exert itself with freedom and security, is so powerful a principle, that it is alone, and without any assistance, not only capable of carrying on the society to wealth and prosperity, but of surmounting a hundred impertinent obstructions, with which the folly of human laws too often encumbers its operations

I want to use

> The natural effort of every individual to better his own condition, when suffered to exert itself with freedom and security, is so powerful a principle, that it is alone, and without any assistance, ... capable of carrying on the society to wealth and prosperity.

I think it is fair enough because the original phrase could also be rewritten as this:

> The natural effort of every individual to better his own condition, when suffered to exert itself with freedom and security, is so powerful a principle, that it is alone, and without any assistance, capable of carrying on the society to wealth and prosperity. Such effort is also capable of surmounting a hundred impertinent obstructions, with which the folly of human laws too often encumbers its operations.

What would convention dictate? Is mine a misquotation?

Comment: The use of ellipses is one of the few exceptions to the need for a verbatim quotation. They indicate that you have deliberately omitted material. If you want to make it explicit that it's *you* using them, you can introduce the quotation with something like *(ellipsis mine)*, in the case of a single ellipsis, to make it clear that it's not a verbatim quote of the *author's* use of ellipses.

Comment: You’re leaving out the point that this is the case *but* (except for) the obstacles placed in the way by the government.

Comment: @Xanne I don't think "but" means "except" here; it indicates a contrast with "only".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right you are. The truncated version still leaves out this important point.